# Folder with umask = 777 but permission denied

Tags: linux

I can't write something on my folder (and subfolder) even if it umask is 0777.
I'm on raspbian and this folder is mount by /etc/fstab at the boot by the line :

```
/dev/sda1       /mnt/usb        ntfs    defaults,umask=0000     0       2
```

This folder is also share in my subnetwork with samba (but even when I if I stop this service, it doesn't solve anything)

If you have any clue, let me know ;)

Here an example of the problem :

```
root@PlexRaspberrypi:/mnt/usb# echo test > test.txt
bash: test.txt: Permission denied
root@PlexRaspberrypi:/mnt/usb# stat "/mnt/usb"
  File: /mnt/usb
  Size: 12288           Blocks: 24         IO Block: 512    directory
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 5           Links: 1
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-10-06 14:20:57.473836800 +0100
Modify: 2019-10-06 13:40:21.070040100 +0100
Change: 2019-10-06 14:20:57.463836800 +0100
 Birth: -
root@PlexRaspberrypi:/mnt/usb#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTFS-3G supports read and write operations:

- Install ntfs-3g: `apt update; apt install ntfs-3g`
- Replace `ntfs` with `ntfs-3g` inside your `/etc/fstab` file.